# Open widget in another window on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

The app opens another widget as a pane. I guess this follows macOS guidelines but is it possible to force widget to open in another window?

[image]

Like this:

[image]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Main Widget");
    w.show();

    QWidget anotherWidget;
    anotherWidget.setWindowTitle("Another Widget");
    anotherWidget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: FWIW when I compile and run the posted code on my Mac, it opens two separate windows (using MacOS/X 10.14.6 and Qt 5.13.0).  AFAICT your code is correct; I think what you want to do is go to the Dock preferences pane in your System Preferences and change the "Prefer tabs when opening documents" setting to some setting other than "Always".

Comment: Sure. Even so I was wondering if there is someway to trap that setting.

Comment: I doubt there's any way to do it from within Qt; there might be some Objective C or CoreFoundation type API for it, but if there is I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to set the flag of the second widget to `Qt::Dialog`

```
QWidget anotherWidget;
anotherWidget.setWindowTitle("Another Widget");
anotherWidget.setWindowFlag(Qt::Dialog);
anotherWidget.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Open the anotherWidget as a QMainWindow type instead of QWidget.

Comment: In my experience that does not make a difference wrt Apple's auto-tabbing behavior.